# Is there a way to find five previous games with MLB-StatsAPI?

Tags: python, api

For those who are familiar with [MLB-StatsAPI](https://pypi.org/project/MLB-StatsAPI/) in Python, I am looking for a way to find the previous five games a team has played. I have tried using `statsai.schedule`, but it will not work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you give which team and opponent you are passing, just so that I can try with he same for you to understand better.

Comment: I am using flask in the project. The point is that the user will enter the home and away teams and the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
import statsapi

sched = statsapi.schedule(start_date='07/01/2018',end_date='07/31/2018',team=143)

newlist = sorted(sched, key = lambda k: k["game_date"], reverse=True)

for game in newlist[0:5]:
    print(game['game_date']+" : "+ str(game['game_id']))
```